# How should I access the checkboxes using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to search for universities and store information using the DAAD website. Here's my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import chromedriver_binary
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/')

searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('suggest')
searchElem.send_keys('Mechanical')
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('filterFos'))
select.select_by_index(3)
select_lang = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('exampleFormControlSelect1'))
select_lang.select_by_index(2)
```

But I get the following error at line 15 (i.e when I try to select the checkbox to choose the degree):

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue. I selected the element then pressed enter to check it.
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.primary').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: @BrandonCampbell What will be the css selector in this case?  "custom-select form-control-lg w-100 u-fs-default c-search__multiselect js-search-multiselect js-filter-element" Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the course option selection is implemented in different way from field of study. It's a drop-down list with check boxes.
So basically when you click in browser on course type you click on different tags then options inside select.
You can change your code to open drop down list, click what you need and close the list

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import chromedriver_binary
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/')

searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('suggest')
searchElem.send_keys('Mechanical')
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('filterFos'))
select.select_by_index(3)
select_lang_fieldset = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="exampleFormControlSelect1"]/parent::fieldset')
# Open dropdown list
select_lang_fieldset.find_element_by_xpath('./div').click()
# Select desired course type
select_lang_fieldset.find_element_by_xpath('./div/ul/li[2]/label/input').click()
# Close dropdown list
select_lang_fieldset.find_element_by_xpath('./div').click()
```

Comment: I ran this and got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="c-multiselect btn-group">...</div> is not clickable at point (435, 592). Other element would receive the click: <div class="c-cookie-compliance__content u-vp--medium">...</div>

Comment: I did it!! The Element to agree to cockies was blocking the drop down element. Thank you so much!